# Unique vs Check constraint

Tags: sql, postgresql, rdbms

I added a Unique constraint and a Check constraint to a PostgreSQL table.

Now when I check details of that table, Unique constraint is listed under 'Indexes', while Check constraint is not.

Why this behaviour?

Comment: A unique constraint is implemented by a unique index, while a check constraint is just a rule which gets checked when an update or insert happens.  Check constraints cannot involve other tables, while a unique constraint can.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See doc here: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/ddl-constraints.html#DDL-CONSTRAINTS-UNIQUE-CONSTRAINTS

> Adding a unique constraint will automatically create a unique B-tree index on the column or group of columns listed in the constraint. A uniqueness restriction covering only some rows cannot be written as a unique constraint, but it is possible to enforce such a restriction by creating a unique partial index.

You see UNIQUE under Indexes is because a unique B-tree index is created.

Comment: This answers half the question.  Why doesn't an index get created for check constraints?  What are the differences between unique and check constraints?

Answer (score 2):

A index is created for a UNIQUE constraint because it is a performant way to check if a value is unique for large tables: you have to check all rows in the table to make sure the value is unique. A index is not created for a CHECK constraint because there is no performance issue: you only have to check the column value(s) for the current row  - you don't need to check all the rows in the table.